# Shortcut to minimize all windows?

Tags: linux-mint, keyboard-shortcuts

In Windows systems, I use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (show desktop) a lot.

I'm using Linux Mint, and I wonder: Can I create a keyboard shortcut that will do the same?

**edit** after the comment from `Gert van den Berg` - if you could explain how to make a short-cut equivalent to <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> that well do.

I think the desktop environment is KDE.

Comment: Which window manager? For example in IceWM Alt-Ctrl-D does the same. Note that depending on the window manager, such command may also be called like “show desktop”.

Comment: @manatwork how do I check what desktiop enviroment I have?

Comment: @elyashiv see http://superuser.com/questions/96151/how-do-i-check-whether-i-am-using-kde-or-gnome

Comment: Technical point: Win+D is "Show Desktop". Win+M is "Minimize all" (https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/27/143042.aspx?Redirected=true explains the difference)

Comment: @GertvandenBerg great link. It's broken now though - current link is https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040527-00/?p=39153

Answer (score 10):

In Linux Mint : <kbd>Start</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> shows the desktop.

Comment: I am using the same version Windows + D works for me.
Go to Keyboard settings->Shortcuts->Click on "Windows"
 :
Find the "Show Desktop" option and set your own shortcut.
Hope it helps..

Comment: Yes, its cinnamon.On the KDE menu type "keyboard" and choose "custom shortcuts". Try there to find shortcut setting. Also, search for "hot corners" -> Show desktop (can be helpful)
Btw try Ctrl+Alt+D if you already haven't.
http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/47 <-- This link shows all the shortcuts which says Ctrl+Alt+D is the one.

Comment: Doesn't work for Ubuntu 15.10 (MATE).

Answer (score 8):

### MATE Desktop Environment

For me, it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

You can find that via Preferences > Hardware > Keyboard and Shortcuts:

[image]

Or start `mate-keybinding-properties` via console.

Look for "Window Management" > "Hide all normal windows and set focus to the Desktop". You can change the shortcut there.

Answer (score 2):

Either <kbd>Start</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will work for minimizing the all open windows.

For Ubuntu  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is the default key for 'Show Desktop'

For Linux Mint in KDE environment, default shortcut for the same is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

See [Keyboard Shortcuts for the KDE Desktop](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/47) link for a full list.

Answer (score 2):

for xfce users, it is also control-alt-d by default. Unlike custom shortcuts, standard window manager shortcuts in xfce are in:
SETTINGS->WINDOW-MANAGER-KEYBOARD.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Mint 18 KDE with Plasma Desktop. Go to Global keyboard shortcuts --> KDE Component: Select Plasma --> Show Desktop.